# Can I call Context.SetError twice to provide 2 values back?

Tags: c#, authentication, owin

As a follow up question to this one:

[OWIN Web api 2 adding additional logic to Bearer authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340088/owin-web-api-2-adding-additional-logic-to-bearer-authorization)

Can I call context.SetError twice like the below, to give 2 values back to the requestor? If not, what's the right way to do that?

```
        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            context.SetError("error_code", 69);

            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, you cannot call it twice.
I found this answer to a similar issue to be very useful in my case:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32934494/6033048

I needed to add an *error_code* besides *error* and *error_description* so I extended *OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext* like in user2325333's example.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so for those people visiting via future search engines:

NO. You cannot call it twice to provide 2 values back. I eventually just serialized (To Json) what I wanted to say and stuffed it into the error_description field. A developer with half a brain would be able to interpret it back into an object and use it appropriately.