# How to customize error message of OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider in asp.net web api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have same problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26336481/how-to-customize-error-message-of-oauthauthorizationserverprovider) .
But when I try this code :

```
            var json = (new MyResponse { message = "The user name or password is incorrect" }).ToJsonString();
            context.SetError(new string(' ',json.Length-12)); 
            context.Response.Write(json);
```

-

```
 public class MyResponse
    {
        public string access_token { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
    }
```

I get "syntax error". Because text response is:

> {"access_token":null,"message":"The user name or password is
>   incorrect"}{"error":"    "}

I can't remove *{"error":" "}*

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the `MyResponse` class that or its parent class could contain a property named `access_token` which is shown in the Response

Fix to get your desired output to create a new response class like this

```
public class MyNewReponse
{
  public string message {get;set;}
}
```

And then create the response using that class

```
var json = (new MyNewReponse { message = "The user name or password is incorrect" }).ToJsonString();
```